# I am trying to show my data obtained from my API but it is not shown I am consuming it with JS

Tags: javascript, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to show my data obtained from my API but it is not shown I am using JS.

```
fetch (" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vehiculo/ ") .then (res => res.json ()) .then (data => muestraData (data))

const muestraData = (data) => {
   let body = '' 
   for (let i = 0; i <data.length; i ++) {
    body + = <tr><td>${data[i].id}</td></tr> 
   }
   document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know how your API response is look like, so in this explanation, I will use (Rick-and-Morty APIs).

> https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

Let's make a function to fetch the data from API:

```js
const loadData = () => {
  return fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Now we can call `loadData` function and build the body:

```js
const data = document.getElementById("data");

loadData().then((response) => {
  const results = response.results;
  let body = "";

  if (results && results.length > 0) {
    results.forEach((item) => {
      body += `ID: ${item.id} <br/>`;
    });
  }

  data.innerHTML = body;
});
```

> Because the `results` variable contains an array of objects, we can just use the `.forEach` method.

> `loadData` returns `Promise`

Working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-forest-utmr3

Comment: thanks Bro I already solved it, your comment is appreciated